# PHP echo as condition inside PHP if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

I would like to use a PHP echo as a condition inside a PHP if statement.

The aim is to have the list of blog articles written by John Doe, displayed on his biography page.

It worked when I directly wrote the author's name in the *if condition*:

```
<!-- current page: biography page -->

<div id="list_of_articles_by_John_Doe">

    <?php foreach(page('magazine')->children() as $article): ?>

        <?php if($article->author() == 'John Doe'): ?>
            <p><?php echo $article->title() ?></p>
        <?php endif ?>

    <?php endforeach ?>

</div>
```

But I would like to automate the process, for each writer's biography page to have their own list of articles.

I tried to have as a condition the author of the current biography page ($page):

```
<!-- current page: biography page -->

<div id="automatic_list_of_articles">

    <?php foreach(page('magazine')->children() as $article): ?>

        <?php if($article->author() == $page->author()): ?>
            <p><?php echo $article->title() ?></p>
        <?php endif ?>

    <?php endforeach ?>

</div>
```

but it makes another issue: it does not work because inside the *foreach statement*, `$page->author()` (condition in the if statement) does not echo the author once, but one time for each `page('magazine')->children() as $article`.

The condition `if($article->author() == $page->author())` does not work in this case, as `$page->author()` is not strictly the writer's name.

I'm wondering how to call `$page->author()` to echo the writer's name only once, when inside the foreach statement.

Comment: I would suggest that you echo out the article author and page author between the foreach and if statement to see if the values are similar. This is the right way to compare: $article->author() == $page->author()) not your echo way

Comment: PHP is not recursively embeddable, and php code embedded in a php string will NOT get executed.

Comment: Attempt echoing your article authors to determine whether or not it is well defined.

Comment: @Raoulito, what is `page('magazine')`, why it is not preseded with `$` as an array/object var and is it wrapped up with `$page->author()`?

Comment: I have provided a working example below, assuming I have interpreted your data correctly.

Comment: man ... the second code block does not have any problem... I think your problem in the values and not in the code,,, but about the third code block , please don't tell anybody about it :(

Comment: Thanks for your help, PHPology was actually right: inside the foreach statement, *$page->author()* echoes the author of the page one time for each *page('magazine')->children() as $article*. So the condition *if($article->author() == $page->author())* doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

What could be an option is to save all author within an array

```
// if article->author() isn't within the array
$authors[] == $article->author();
```

After that you could go as the following:

```
<?php foreach($authors as $author){ ?>
    <?php foreach(page('magazine')->children() as $article): ?>

        <?php if($article->author() == $author()): ?>
            <p><?php echo $article->title() ?></p>
        <?php endif ?>

    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php } ?>
```

That should work, even if you must do 2 foreachs

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php if( $article->author() == $page->author() ) { ?>
        <p><?php echo $article->title(); ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
```

should work, but you can also try

```
    <?php 
    if( $article->author() == $page->author() ) {
        echo "\n<p>", $article->title(), "</p>\n";
    }
    ?>
```

which to me looks "cleaner"; but you'd have to have a look for missing whitespaces

Comment: That won't work as he saind that $page->author() only echos one article

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't get the question right. Now I do, but I don't understand Raoulito's intension.

Comment: he'S trying to find a way to get all article titles sorted by the author

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to set it equal too a variable and then using that variable in the if statement.

```
<?php foreach(page('magazine')->children() as $article): ?>

    <?php $condition = $page->author()?>

    <?php if($article->author() == $condition  ?>'): ?>
         echo "\n<p>", $article->title(), "</p>\n";
    <?php endif ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

I am not sure if my syntax is correct but i think it is something along them lines.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you shouldn't have this?

```
<div id="automatic_list_of_articles">

    <?php $page = page('magazine'); ?>

    <?php foreach($page->children() as $article): ?>

        <?php if($article->author() == $page->author()): ?>
            <p><?php echo $article->title() ?></p>
        <?php endif ?>

    <?php endforeach ?>

</div>
```

I have reconstructed an approximation of what looks to be your data, and you can see it working at the link below. It correctly echo's multiple article titles.

**Working example:**

http://ideone.com/jvLVhF

In this example you can see the PHP as above works correctly, and it is likely a data issue (ie. you should perhaps be using $page and not calling a function in the foreach statement).

Comment: The issue is actually that inside `foreach($page->children() as $article):` the writer's name `$page->author()` gets echoed one time for each `$page->children() as $article`. So the *if condition* cannot work anymore.

Comment: It works fine in the example - the output is at the bottom of the link. Of course this makes an assumption about the shape of your data, if you can provide more detail about the data structure involved I am happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use echo in condition because it is special language construct that sends given contents to the output stream and it returns no value.

Comment: I don't see any use of the echo statements return value (or lack thereof).